# how to take difference of dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar2 column open_time in a table. Now i need to find out the records where difference between open_time and sysdate is greater than 180.

Comment: open time is in days?

Comment: Greater than 180 what?  Seconds?  Minutes?  Hours?  Days?  Years?

Comment: open time is a date stored in varchar2 field. need difference of days

Comment: Never, ever store dates as `varchar`. Just don't

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what the values in `OPEN_TIME` look like. By this, I mean are they stored as e.g. `13-JUN-2015 01:02:03 PM` or `01/13/15 13:02:03` or what? If there are a variety of different "styles" of dates stored in this field please give examples of them all. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast a varchar2 to a date using the `TO_DATE` function. The format you need to specify depends on the format in which your date is stored.

Once you've got a date value, you can subtract it from `sysdate` to get the (fractional) number of days. So to check if your date is more than 180 days ago, you could write:

```
WHERE sysdate - ThatDateValue > 180
```

in other words:

```
WHERE sysdate - TO_DATE(open_time, 'FORMAT') > 180
```

where FORMAT is the format that matches your date. I can't give it, since you didn't specify any example dates, but the possible format parameter are well-documented if you check out the [`TO_DATE` documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

But as a suggestion: Storing dates in a `varchar2` is a bad idea. There is `date` for that. It's more efficient to not have to convert the text to a date every time, it prevents storing illegal dates, and it makes it easier to do date calculation. I'd replace the varchar2 column with a date column if you have the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract two dates you get a number that is the amount of days between the two dates, so you can subtract open_time from sysdate and then do a check if the outcome is greater than 180

ex.

```
SELECT
 --COLUMNS
FROM
 --TABLES
WHERE
 (SYSDATE - open_time) > 180
```

Missed the varchar part, but the other answer mentions the TO_DATE function which is an easy fix. just throw a TO_DATE around open_time

Answer (score 0):

If open_time is in days, it seems pretty easy.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE open_time > 180
```

if its a date, try using datediff?